# Joda-Time: Test if a LocalDate falls in a duration

Tags: java, jodatime

What is an efficient and easy-to-read expression of testing if `LocalDate dayX` falls in a duration that is described with a starting day `LocalDate day0` and a length `Period length`?

Currently I am doing like this:

```
boolean match = !day0.isAfter(dayX) && day0.plus(length).isAfter(dayX);
```

I just feel this looks a bit dumb and every time I read this it takes several seconds for my brain to tell if the boundaries are correct. So I am looking for a smarter way that maybe involves the `Duration` or `Interval` classes.

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct (except that you need to use `before` method for the first condition). Maybe you can wrap it into a method and call it to make it reusable and look more elegant, e.g.:

```
public boolean isInRange(Localdate start, Period period, Localdate target){
   return !target.before(start) && !target.after(start.plus(period));
}
```

Comment: Oh, you are right. That's what I meant when I said about my brain calculating. Lol. I'm going to modify the question.

Comment: Wait, wait, it's the same, isn't it? `day0.isAfter(dayX) === dayX.isBefore(day0)`

Comment: Yes, it's the same. However, you need to use both `before` and `after` if positions of parameters are going to remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar approach: day0 < dayx < (day0 + period)

```
boolean match =  (dayx.isAfter(day0) && dayx.isBefore(day0.plus(length));
```

Comment: This will return false when `day0 == dayX`, which is not exactly what I wanted.

Comment: ok, so we make the condition as day0 <= dayx < (day0 + period)                     
              boolean match =  (dayx.isEqual(day0)|| dayx.isAfter(day0)) && dayx.isBefore(day0.plus(length));

Comment: But then it does not fulfill the simplicity you are looking for.